# bulk rename mp3 songs

Tags: linux, rename

I have hundreds of thousands of .mp3 songs recovered with testdisk and producing results such as in a directory:

```
f196833984.mp3
```

however, when loaded in Rhythmbox, they show up as originally tagged.

what I want to do is remove the naming and replace with the tagged information and see that in also in the directory.

Here is an image of what all looks like now.
[image]

here is the output of

```
id3v2 -l f194867904.mp3
```

from id3v2:

```
> id3v1 tag info for f194867904.mp3:
Title  : "Sempre libera"                 Artist: Anna Netrebko                 
Album  : Rolando Villaz�n / Violetta -   Year: 2005, Genre: Classical (32)
Comment: Easy CD-DA Extractor            Track: 5
id3v2 tag info for f194867904.mp3:
TIT2 (Title/songname/content description): "Sempre libera"
TPE1 (Lead performer(s)/Soloist(s)): Anna Netrebko
TPE2 (Band/orchestra/accompaniment): Anna Netrebko
TALB (Album/Movie/Show title): Rolando Villazón / Violetta - Arias and Duets from Verdi's La Traviata
TYER (Year): 2005
COMM (Comments): ()[XXX]: Easy CD-DA Extractor
TCON (Content type): Classical (32)
TRCK (Track number/Position in set): 5
```

Thanks a lot. I post now the result as image which shows exactly what I did and the results. The image far left is the folder that had the songs listed in the Terminal, far right. Where the songs went, I do not know. But it left one behind, that I'm enjoying as I type this. You can see that in VLC, also in the image below.
[image]

Comment: The first idea coming to my mind is a shell script which reads the id3 tags (eg with id3v2) and copies / moves the file with the new name to another directory.

Comment: that would be ideal. but i do not have the skills for it, though i am ready to learn. so, we wait and hopefully someone smarter than us would stop by..... thanks a lot, however.

Comment: The question is: do you have the good informations with id3v2 gordon ? If yes, please add sample output

Comment: There are a couple of tools I came across `id3tool` and `mediainfo` they aren't part of the standard repository in **Archlinux** but you can download/compile/install if you need to.  From there its a matter of running over your directory tokenizing the results and renaming files.

Comment: Well, I don't know about rhythmbox, but I know clementine, another music player/library manager, has an excellent "organize files" dialog that will do that for you and allow you to specify naming, creation of artist/album directories etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But that did not help. Or, I do not know how to use it.

Comment: For that example in your question what would be your ideal filename and/or directory name(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not wedded to the idea of a shell script, I really like [puddletag](https://docs.puddletag.net/download.html) to manage tags on my music files. You can [bulk rename files based on tags](https://docs.puddletag.net/source/function.html#tag-to-filename) with a few mouse clicks.

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EasyTAG offers this feature including a GUI with a preview feature. I regard it more safe than a the bash-script in the other answer.

Comment: @Hermann I've used EasyTAG too, and it's also good. I prefer puddletag's interface. Probably a personal thing. OP should try both.

Comment: thanks a lot. i have tried puddletag and that's great! with a single click of the "F" button, all files were renamed based on the tag information encoded in them. great and neat tool. i love it. i can't seem to find cddb or any such on it, however. and easytag still has issues with cddb. so picard it is for now. but it would be nice to have both functions in one application.

Comment: @gordoncomstock Under the "Window" menu, select "Tag Sources". This won't let you use cddb---I don't remember why---but it'll let you use several other good sites.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a **for-loop** to iterate through every file in the directory.

Each iteration will use **ffprobe** to dump tags, and then **grep** to filter text and get *title* and *artist* as clean text strings in separate vars.

Then finally rename the file into: 'Artist - Title.ext'

---

**IMPORTANT:** Copy a few of those files to a new, separate (and otherwise empty) directory.

Then do a test run of any scripts on the content of that directory before you run the script on all those files... It may help you avoid data loss if something unexpected hsppens.

---

**Example:**

```bash
for fN in * ;do
  strTags="$(2>&1 ffprobe -loglevel quiet -show_entries format_tags=artist,title "${fN}"|grep 'TAG:.*=.*$')"

  strTitle="$(echo "${strTags}"|grep 'TAG:title=.*$')"
  strArtist="$(echo "${strTags}"|grep 'TAG:artist=.*$')"

  mv "${fN}" "${strArtist:10}"' - '"${strTitle:9}${fN: -4:4}"

done
```

Comment: I have done this, but after running the script, it changes "script.sh" which is the name of the script, to " - t.sh" and does nothing to the directory with the songs.

Comment: My example doesn't use a *script.sh* file.

Comment: and without putting your example in a script, which i named 'script.sh' can you please say how you intend I use it?

Comment: @gordoncomstock They are **commands** they do work without script files if you simply type (or copy-paste) them to the **command line** of any bash shell(or compatible) where ffmpeg is installed. **NOTE: PASTING NEW-LINE CHATACTERS TO CONSOLE IS NOT ALWAYS ADVISABLE**

Comment: @gordoncomstock If you add the example inside a **function** in a script file, and then **source it** instead of running it, then you have added all that code to a single command that can be executed in any directory, regardless of where the script file is saved...

Answer (score -1):

**READ THE WHOLE POST BEFORE DOING ANYTHING**

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in $(ls $1)
do
  line=$(id3v2 -l $file | sed -n '2p')
  title=$(echo $line | cut -d '"' -f 2 | sed 's/ /_/g')
  artist=$(echo $line | cut -d ':' -f 3 | awk '{$1=$1};1' | sed 's/ /_/g')
  mv $1/$file $1/$artist-$title
done
```

This should rename each file to <artist name > <song title> with a dash inbetween.

Save it as something (eg. script.sh), make it executable (chmod +x script.sh), and then run it, specifying the target directory after, eg:

```
./script.sh <target directory>
```

**MAKE SURE ONLY SONGS YOU WANT TO RENAME ARE IN THE TARGET DIRECTORY**
**MAKE SURE THE SYNTAX IS CORRECT BEFORE PRESSING ENTER**
**I ONLY TESTED THIS ON THE SAMPLE YOU POSTED**

Improper usage of this can *mess up your system* if this script ends up getting fed a bad ls call. To avoid any other potential problems I would recommend creating a new directory, copying maybe 5-10 songs over, and running the script there to verify it works properly and to your liking.

**USE AT YOUR OWN RISK**

Comment: Use more quotes. See    
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes>    
<http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments>    
<http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words>    

And The backquote (```) is used in the old-style command substitution, e.g. foo=`command`. The foo=$(command) syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside $() is less surprising, and $() is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

Comment: Good info, thanks.

Comment: The first thing I noticed was that you call `id3v2` twice on each file. With "hundreds of thousands of .mp3 songs" to process that tiny overhead might becomes quite a bit of time, so it might be smarter to save the entire output of `id3v2` to a variable and then extract the artist and title from there.

Comment: @henriksupportsthecommunity good point

Comment: Nice idea, but this implementation needs improvement. As it stands, it won't handle input files with white-space in their names (okay, OP does not currently have those, but still bad practice). It replaces spaces with underscores, but other white-space (e.g. tab) will mess up the output. In case of empty tags, this will (by overwriting) happily delete all files except for the last (should use `mv -i` at minimum).

Comment: and you're right, my updated image shows that it did delete all the files, except one.

Comment: @gordoncomstock I had actually stopped updating this because the other answer suggesting puddletag/easytag seemed to be a much better & cleaner solution. Did you try those?